# Configure GSA to only crawl metadata of files, not content

Tags: google-search, google-search-appliance

In GSA (Google Search Appliance), I am looking into how I can have it crawl only the metadata (name, type, size, last modified, etc) and not the content of the file. While I realize this can affect the usefulness of the results, I have my requirements.

It comes down to the metadata of the file is public, but the content of the file is restricted. While this seems like a security-trimmed question, it's slightly more because I don't want GSA to store ANY information on the content of the file in the index. Assume the GSA server is untrusted to hold the content. This is only for a small subset of the whole dataset.

Any ideas on how I could configure GSA and connectors to only crawl the metadata and not the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this from crawling files(on fileshare or on website)
You can however do this by crawling a **DB** with the columns containing the meta data or by developing a connector that only creates a **feed** that provides the meta data.

This will work if you have the metadata stored somewhere, but not together in the file.

Another option is to customise your front end to not provide a link to the document and just configure the meta data to be displayed in the result. (Use **1** in the FrontEnd to automatically display the meta data fields)
You will also need to add the '**getfields**' parameter in the search query to include the relevant meta data fields.

This works for a DB scenario. Have not tested it with file meta data, but should work.

Duncan de Klerk
Conor

Comment: If it crawls the DB, how does it get a link to the file to be displayed in the search results?

Comment: IrishBoiler, you would need a column that provides a link to the file.

Comment: @Riley I missed the notification and just came back to this question. Your comment was the missing piece of the puzzle in my head to Duncan's answer.